# create pem from ecc signature bytes

Tags: encryption, qnx

I am researching an QNX ARM based car navigation and it seems this system has a backdoor that enables telnet access without password to the system if a challenge/response succeeds.

When a file called `challenge` is placed on a USB key and inserted in the system it will write some bytes in it. Here are a few examples:
eaxj2ABs4BeMQqQJamOH?smOCVEC
KKUcw5m:vvJXmCIK3SBDDqv9p:Or
odlwY@ed6B?8OKCmaqIDdFz7YSnv
BBqGoWKocmAuvSDacMAkZ:83:QVq

I found the ELF file that handles the challenge/response in the firmware (can share this upon request) and it reads a public key file:
`hChallengePub = sub_1030A0((int)"/ifs/challenge.pub", &v11, &v13)`

challenge.pub contains the following bytes:

```
30 29 03 02 07 00 02 01 0E 02 0F 00 9C 9C A4 5A
FA 1E 2D 32 2A 93 9D 37 41 93 02 0F 00 95 AB 6B
DB 94 29 4D C3 C6 07 3B B7 31 40
```

Debug text in the ELF points to source file `src/pk/ecc/ecc_import.c` which leds me to believe it's an ECC public key but it seems to be incomplete (eg no ASN.1 header).

I want to be able to convert this key into pem format so I can run some tests with openssl so I am looking for pointers how to do this.

Ultimately I'd like to see if I can create proper response and get access but maybe this is impossible if it requires private key (which it should if it's any good).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`src/pk/ecc/ecc_import.c` strongly suggests that it's using LibTomCrypt: https://github.com/libtom/libtomcrypt/blob/develop/src/pk/ecc/ecc_import.c

The content of `challenge.pub` appears to be DER-encoded. [It can be decoded as follows](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#30290302070002010E020F009C9CA45AFA1E2D322A939D374193020F0095AB6BDB94294DC3C6073BB73140):

```
SEQUENCE(4 elem)
    BIT STRING (1 bit) 0
    INTEGER            14
    INTEGER (112 bit)  3176466357047968568460177262985619
    INTEGER (112 bit)  3035660427084515633934604600553792
```

As can be seen in the `ecc_import.c` code referenced above, this translates to:

- `key->type` = `PK_PUBLIC`
- `key_size` = `14` bytes
- `key->pubkey.x` = `3176466357047968568460177262985619`
- `key->pubkey.y` = `3035660427084515633934604600553792`

Comment: How to verify it with openssl ? `openssl ec -noout -text -inform DER -in challenge.pub -pubin` fails:
`read EC key
unable to load Key
24340:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1198:
24340:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:372:Type=X509_ALGOR
24340:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:694:Field=algor, Type=X509_PUBKEY`

Missing ASN1 ?

Comment: LibTomCrypt uses a different format than openssl expects. See http://superuser.com/questions/900918/get-x-and-y-components-of-ec-public-key-using-openssl#comment1207840_900918 for openssl's expected format.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it's very helpful (would still like to convert to OpenSSL compatible PEM format but I will research that)